# Powershell correctly use include keyword

Tags: powershell

This is my script which is working fine.

```
$include = @(
    'File.M*'
    'ABC.M*' 
    'XYZ.M*'
)
```

At the end there is `.M*`.  Is there anyway that I can simply use the common `.M*` outside of the bracket? Something like this:

```
 $include= @((
    "File"
    "ABC" 
    "XYZ"
    )+.M*)
```

Comment: nope. each item in the array of patterns must be complete in itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly like that, but you could do

```
$include = @(
    'File'
    'ABC' 
    'XYZ'
) | ForEach-Object {$_ + ".M*"}
```

and get the same thing

```
File.M*
ABC.M* 
XYZ.M*
```

Another way would be to use `-replace` and regex.

```
$include = @(
    'File'
    'ABC' 
    'XYZ'
) -replace '$', '.M*'
```

Note: `$` is the position at the end of each line

Comment: Loving the regex solution as much as hating the loop solution :)